# parent_params: update nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

(Preface/disclaimer: I'd like to know what it is that I should learn in order to prevent such errors in the future. I'm new to programming and have been reading about strong params all day, but it hasn’t seemed to solve the issue)

I have two models: Artist (Parent), and Song (Child), with a has_many / belongs_to relationship. I use a nested attributes form_for @parent in order to create a child object, with all of my code in the parents_controller. (There is also a join table between User and Child, called “UserSong” in the code).

Everything gets created fine, but when I click “edit” on the show page for the child, I get a form with all of the child objects instead of just the specific child object I clicked on - not what I want, but the main issue is that when I then proceed to edit a child object and press “submit”, I get a `NoMethodError in ParentsController#update`, specifying `private method ‘update’ called for nil:NilClass`, that I just simply can’t seem to get rid of.

The line of code that gets highlighted is `if @parent.update(parent_params)`, which I’ve put in bold in the code below.

parents_controller:

```
class ArtistsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def create
    @artist = Artist.find_or_create_by(name: params[:artist][:name].strip.titleize)
    @song = @artist.songs.find_or_create_by(title: params[:artist][:songs_attributes]["0"][:title].strip.titleize) do |song|
      song.lyrics = params[:artist][:songs_attributes]["0"][:lyrics].strip
    end
    @user_song = current_user.user_songs.find_or_create_by(song_id: @song.id) do |user_id|
      user_id.user_id = current_user.id
    end
    redirect_to root_path
  end

  def index
    @songs = Song.all
  end

  def new
    @artist = Artist.new
    @artist.songs.build
    @user_song = UserSong.new(user_id: current_user.id, song_id: @song)
  end

  def show
    @song = Song.find(params[:id])
  end

  def destroy
    UserSong.where(:song_id => params[:id]).first.destroy
    flash[:success] = "The song has been removed from your playlist"
    redirect_to root_path
  end

  def edit
    @song = Song.find(params[:id])
    @artist = @song.artist
  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @artist.update(artist_params)
        format.html { redirect_to session.delete(:return_to), notice: 'Song/Artist was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @artist.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  private

  def artist_params
    params.require(:artist).permit(:id, :name, songs_attributes: [:id, :title, :lyrics])
  end
end
```

The form looks like this:

```
<%= form_for @artist do |f| %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.text_field :name, placeholder: "Artist", class: "form-control" %>
  </div>

  <%= f.fields_for :songs do |p| %>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= p.text_field :title, placeholder: "Song title", class: "form-control" %>
      <br />
      <%= p.text_area :lyrics, placeholder: "Input lyrics here", rows: 20, class: "form-control" %>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.submit "Add song" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Any clues pointing me in the right direction would be much appreciated!

edit: if it helps, I've posted the relevant routes below:

```
         artists GET    /artists(.:format)                 artists#index
                 POST   /artists(.:format)                 artists#create
      new_artist GET    /artists/new(.:format)             artists#new
     edit_artist GET    /artists/:id/edit(.:format)        artists#edit
          artist GET    /artists/:id(.:format)             artists#show
                 PATCH  /artists/:id(.:format)             artists#update
                 PUT    /artists/:id(.:format)             artists#update
                 DELETE /artists/:id(.:format)             artists#destroy
           songs GET    /songs(.:format)                   artists#index
                 POST   /songs(.:format)                   artists#create
        new_song GET    /songs/new(.:format)               artists#new
       edit_song GET    /songs/:id/edit(.:format)          artists#edit
            song GET    /songs/:id(.:format)               artists#show
                 PATCH  /songs/:id(.:format)               artists#update
                 PUT    /songs/:id(.:format)               artists#update
                 DELETE /songs/:id(.:format)               artists#destroy
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The request fails because `@artist` is nil in your update action, you need to load the value with something like:

```
@artist = Artist.find(params[:id])
```

Instance variables exist only in the scope of request at a time, so you always need to load the values you need per request. (Like how you load the `@song` value in the show/edit actions.

Additionally, the reason that all of the child objects load is that `<%= f.fields_for :songs do |p| %>` loads all of the artist's songs (it's the equivalent of calling `@artist.songs`. If you just want the one song, try:

```
<%= f.fields_for :songs, @song do |p| %>
```

This will load the `fields_for` for list with just the one song.

Comment: This did it. You're the man. Two days of debugging resolved in 5 minutes... I'm not sure if I should feel overjoyed, or annoyed with myself... lol

Comment: Nine times out of ten nil errors result from a failure to initialize a variable (one of the downsides of Ruby).

Comment: Why is this a downside?